# Summing .tiff files using if-statement

Tags: python

Context:

I am attempting to sum .tiff files containing monthly evapotranspiration per year (e.g. sum all twelve months for 2007) to get an annual total evapotranspiration. However, the "if in" (see code) statement does not seem to filter for only the year 2007, causing all .tiff files for all years in the specified directory to be summed.

Question:

How can I make sure only the .tiff files are summed according to a specific year (in this example 2007)?

```
def pathList (d): # d is the path to the specified directory
   
   sum_array = np.zeros((2200, 2800)) # creating empty array in which to sum monthly evap. values
   nmlist = [] # creates an empty list object in which to store the names of the .tiff files
   count = 0 # creating variable to store index of files in directory

   for item in os.scandir(d): # iterating through directory contents
     
            nmlist.append(item.name) # preparing name list of .tiff files to use in "if in" statement (see below)

            tif_file = gdal.Open(pthlist[count]) # reading .tiff via gdal
            tif_band = tif_file.GetRasterBand(1) # reading first band
            tif_arr = tif_band.ReadAsArray() # converting to numpy array
            
            if "2007" in nmlist[count]: # does the name of the file contain a specific year (e.g. 2007)?
                sum_array = sum_array + tif_arr # summing monthly evap. values
       
            count += 1 # tracking index of files in directory

   return sum_array
```

See [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJS1B.png) for sample of names of .tiff files.

See (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19qeuDblRh_AwQ-BMHz-KvP6np2lqAlH5?usp=sharing) for two examples of the .tiff files I am using.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Mmmm... if you are not interested in files without "2007" in their name you would do better to check first before bothering to open and load unwanted files. Also, try printing out the value and type of `nmlist[count]` prior to testing for presence of "2007" like this `print(f'Count: {count}, nmlist[count]: {nmlist[count]}, type(nmlist[count]): {type(nmlist[count])}')`

Comment: Most likely your error is in this line: `tif_file = gdal.Open(pthlist[count])`. You don't open `item` or `item.name` (aka `nmlist[count]`), but instead open some entry from an array `pthlist`, which is defined nowhere in your function. Is it possible that the order of the elements in `pthlist` is different from the order of elements returned by `os.scandir` (and therefore, different from the order of elements in `nmlist`)? In that case, checking whether, say, the third element in `nmlist` contains 2007 in the name does nothing to ensure that the third entry of `pthlist` does the same.

Comment: Also, please ensure that all the information to answer your question is contained in your question on SO, not hidden behind links (i.e. embed your screenshots).

Comment: @cemper93 Thank you for the help, I could solve my issue with your advice!

Comment: @TimKerremans I am glad I could help. I've re-posted my comment as an answer, so you can accept it if you want (and thereby mark your question resolved).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your error is in this line: `tif_file = gdal.Open(pthlist[count])`. You don't open `item` or `item.name` (aka `nmlist[count]`), but instead open some entry from an array `pthlist`, which is defined nowhere in your function. Is it possible that the order of the elements in `pthlist` is different from the order of elements returned by os`.scandir` (and therefore, different from the order of elements in `nmlist`)? In that case, checking whether, say, the third element in `nmlist` contains "2007" in the name does nothing to ensure that the third entry of `pthlist` does the same.